# -5/0 volt to 0/5 volt logic levels?

Tags: integrated-circuit, level-shifting, logic-level

Does anyone know a good way to convert -5/0 volt logic to 0/5 volt? I'm using a chip as seen in the diagram below, but I'm not sure what to do about the inverted logic levels. Basically, I need to add 5 volts to both logic levels to fix it (-5 volt goes to 0, 0 volts goes to 5). I know I can do the level shifting with some MOSFETs, but I'm space limited on the board so it would be really helpful if anyone could recommend an IC to do the conversion. If there is no such IC, what would be the best discrete circuit to do the conversion?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: How fast are you running the data lines at?

Comment: Replace the -5V symbols with ground symbols, and the ground symbols with 5V symbols. Tada!

Comment: Also, just how much real estate do you have to play with here?

Comment: @matt-young ; The schematics was copied from ADN8810's datasheet, labeled "Driving Common Anode to Ground Laser Diodes with a Negative Supply"

Comment: @TEMLIB I'm fully aware.

Comment: Related question: [Translating to “below ground” logic levels](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60029/) Note the transistor array mentioned in my answer lets you pack a bunch of discretes in a tiny space.

Comment: @matt-young: It would be ideal if I could do that, but the laser diode is part of a TOSA module, which is constructed with common anode which must be at ground.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: I have just under 1 cm^2 available at present. I might be able to move some other things around to make a little more room, but that's going to be tough.

Comment: Since all of those logic signals appear to be inputs to the ADN8810, don't you actually need to subtract 5V so that 'normal' 0 to 5V gets turned into -5V to 0?

Comment: @AlexandraEllis -- I take it that TOSA module has a metal case that's bonded to the anode?

Answer (score 2):

You could try digital isolators :

[image]

http://www.analog.com/en/products/interface-isolation/isolation/quad-channel-standard-isolators/adum240e.html

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso7840.pdf

Not very small, and probably more expensive than discrete transistors.

There are dozens of references.

Comment: Yep, or optocouplers if there is room.  The digital isolator is probably smaller but harder to buy.

Comment: @TEMLIB: That's interesting, I've never worked with digital isolators. Cost isn't really a killer for me. I had considered optocouplers, but board space was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that could be done using "jellybean"-ish op amps and resistors, one idea would be to use a summing circuit as a level shifter, like so, repeated for each signal:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9cO2B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistor values shown are examples, and the AD822 can be replaced by any RRIO op amp.  This doesn't provide any isolation, and requires both the +5V and -5V supplies to share a common ground, though -- I'm not sure if that's a + or a - in your application.